# Windows updates stuck because didn't disable deep freeze

Tags: windows, freeze, updates

Ok so i'm a special kind of stupid, here is the thing, i'm installing Windows  update and i had deep freeze installed and i forgot to thawed the computer, so now i'm stuck with the updates, Please help

Comment: If your system is configured with Deep Freeze, then shouldn’t a simple reboot, dispose of your changes and restore the frozen configuration?  If you are not an Administrator with the ability to unfreeze your system then this problem cannot be solved by you

Comment: More details are required. What "deep freeze" program are you using? What has actually happened? What symptoms are there? What have you tried so far? "I forgot" and "I'm stuck" doesn't really help anyone know what is going on.

Comment: I would assume the author is talking about Faronics Deep Freeze.

Comment: If so then potential things to try: https://superuser.com/questions/310053/windows-7-deep-freeze-im-stuck-in-an-endless-reboot-loop?rq=1

Comment: What Operating system?

Comment: Ok yes, i'm using windows 10, faronics deep freeze and i've tried to enter winRE without success, once i turn on the laptop it automatically starts to install the updates, it says " working on windows updates" it reaches 100% fast, after thai it says " cleaning" and it reaches 100 % after a  few minutes then the laptop automatically shuts down, when i turn it back on it does the same thing.

Comment: What does "thawed the computer" mean?

Comment: To unfreeze it, sorry English is not my first language, anyway @Mokubai 's link was exactly hay i needed, I just enter the setup and foward the date two years to disable Deep Freeze so that the updates could be installed,  thank you all, you guys are the best!!!!